# Device names for logical volumes

Tags: linux, lvm

Consider this:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 298.9 GB, 298999349248 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 36351 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              14       36351   291884985   8e  Linux LVM
```

and this

```
# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                     276883300   3610240 258981300   2% /
/dev/sda1               101086     19371     76496  21% /boot
tmpfs                  1993292         0   1993292   0% /dev/shm
```

*(The OS is Centos 5.5 64-bit, the HW is IBM ServeRAID M1015 using an LSI MegaRAID BIOS)*

Why does `df` use a long filesystem name instead of `/dev/sda2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df` shows you mounted filesystems, which reside on block devices. `fdisk` is showing you the partition table on your /dev/sda block device. Since you don't have a filesystem mounted directly on /dev/sda2, you won't see it appear in `df` output. Your root filesystem (the first entry in `df`) is on an LVM logical volume, which, after consulting your fdisk output, is likely in turn on an LVM physical volume on /dev/sda2.

When comparing block device names in `df` output with those in output from the LVM management utilities, it helps to know that the kernel uses the full device name for df (here it's /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00). The device mapper creates convenient symlinks in /dev that correspond with your volume group names. You can correlate the two outputs by ignoring the "mapper" portion of the name in df, and replacing the hyphen with a forward slash. Running `ls -al /dev/VolGroup00` will illustrate the relationship for you.

This doesn't really have anything to do with hardware raid. These utilities would give you the same information regardless of controller type.